# Connect Snowflake to Azure analysis services to build cube

Tags: azure, azure-analysis-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to build cube on Azure analysis services by connecting to Snowflake DB.

Seems Azure analysis services does not provide a connector to snowflake. Can anyone suggest how to overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, on your laptop install both the [32-bit and 64-bit ODBC driver](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/odbc-download.html) for Snowflake. Then open the "ODBC Data Sources (32-bit)" and create a new system DSN called "Snowflake" using the Snowflake ODBC driver. Repeat in the "ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)" app creating another system DSN named identically as the 32-bit one. Make sure you set tracing=0 in both 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC connection dialog properties as it kills cube processing performance to set tracing=6.

Next, on an appropriate VM (preferably an Azure VM in the same Azure region as Snowflake) ensure the [On-premises Data Gateway is setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway?) for Azure Analysis Services. (Though Snowflake is not on-premises, it's not a [supported cloud data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-datasource?), so it must use the gateway.) On that VM, repeat the above ODBC steps.

In Visual Studio, choose File... New... Project... Analysis Services... Tabular... Analysis Services Tabular Project. Choose compatibility mode "SQL Server 2017/Azure Analysis Services (1400)" and choose "Integrated workspace".

Then in Tabular Model Explorer right click the Data Sources folder and choose "Add Data Source". Choose ODBC as the data source and then choose your DSN name from the dropdown.

Choose which tables you wish to import. Once the model is ready to deploy, deploy to Azure Analysis Services and it should use the ODBC driver on the gateway VM to connect to Snowflake.

Comment: Than you Greg, I tried the above steps and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Do you know how to automate and setup hourly data refresh for the cube ?

Comment: @Feisal what’s your automation tool for the load of the DW and everything else?

Comment: i will be using only power shell to schedule the cube refresh

Comment: @Feisal PowerShell in Azure Automation runbooks? Or on-premises PowerShell. The approach is similar but different.

Comment: It is an Azure runbook.

Comment: @Feisal I would start by studying this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-refresh-azure-automation and then which shows how to do a full refresh of the whole cube every time. If you need incremental processing (just a subset of tables/partitions) then probably best to ask a new question on that topic.