# Using Snowflake database as a SSAS (SQL Server Analysis Services) datasource?

Tags: odbc, ssas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We "need" to feed our SSAS Tabular models with [Snowflake](https://www.snowflake.com) data (through ODBC because we have no Snowflake connector).

We tried with SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server 2017 and get atrocious performance (few rows a second...).

Under PowerBI, there is a Snowflake connector and it's fast.

I came across a [thread](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Getting-Started-With-Snowflake-Database-Making-it-Faster/ta-p/514741) from someone having an apparently similar speed problem when trying to feed Snowflake data to SAS.

He seems to have solved his problem by specifying some (ODBC?) parameters:

- dbcommit = 10000
- autocommit = no
- readbuff = 200
- insertbuff = 200

Are these parameters specific to Snowflake? Or just ODBC?

Thanks

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions for SSAS Tabular models in Azure Analysis Services are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56433455/5070440). Everything except the On Premises Data Gateway should apply to you.

Make sure you check whether tracing=0 in your ODBC data source as tracing=6 killed performance for me.

Comment: our problem was "tracing=6" too

Answer (score 2):

These are SAS options, not ODBC or Snowflake.

For the load issue, ODBC row by row inserts is typically a slow approach.

Is there an option for you to export the data to S3 or Blob and then bulk load in SSAS before running your models - or alternatively could you push down the queries to Snowflake itself?

Comment: In addition, I'd suggest checking this article - not sure if this will be useful here or not: https://www.cdata.com/blog/bigdata_nosql/20190411-snowflake-ssas

Comment: However... How do you import S3 data to SSAS (on premise)?