# Can we use Snowflake cloud data from within Azure Analysis Services?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

We are currently using on-premises SSAS-Tabular cubes feeding from the Snowflake Cloud database.

We achieve this using ODBC Drivers to Snowflake.
So far so good but it requires setting up an ODBC datasource on the SQL Server machine itself.

We would like to test/use Azure Analysis Services instead.
We deployed our cube to Azure but cannot process it because we do not have our ODBC drivers setup in Azure.

Is there a way to access Snowflake Cloud database from within Azure Analysis Services?

Thanks

Comment: This has been answered before [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56372891/connect-snowflake-to-azure-analysis-services-to-build-cube)

Comment: And note that Snowflake is a supported data source for Power BI, Power BI Premium, and Power BI Embedded. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources  It's one of the (now many) gaps between AAS and Power BI.

Comment: I think @Sergiu answer above should solve our problem since it goes through ODBC...

Comment: Thanks for these answers. Both are extremely useful